# Different way to see that $\int_{-c}^c \text{d}{x}/x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

The other day, I stumbled across the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-c}^c\text{d}{x}\frac{1}{x}
\end{equation}
with $c$, a positive real number. Now, it seems to me obvious that this integral should yield zero since it is odd with respect to $x=0$. **However, how can one prove this ?**  It seems that the result depends on how one takes the limit for the $x=0$ singularity. For instance, consider:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-c}^c\text{d}{x}\frac{1}{x}=\lim_{\tilde\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\int_{-c}^{-\tilde\epsilon}\frac{\text{d}{x}}{x}+\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{c}\frac{\text{d}{x}}{x}
\end{equation}
The result of the latter expression depends on how one takes the $\epsilon,\tilde\epsilon$ limit... I am a bit confused on how to proceed.

Comment: In the traditional sense the integral diverges, just look at what happens at the origo. But the *principal value* converges to zero as you correctly asserted, by looking at 
$$
\int_{-c}^c \frac{dx}{x} = \Big[\log |x| \Big]_{-c}^c
= \log|c| - \log|-c| = \log c - \log c = 0
$$

Comment: Indeed, the integral doesn't exist unless you mean the principal value (let $\epsilon = \tilde{\epsilon}$ approach zero together)

Comment: @MPW : But because this integral depends on wether I mean the principal value or not, does this imply that this integral is ill-defined for a Riemann integral ?

Comment: You need to take the principal value $\epsilon = \tilde \epsilon$ - else suppose you take $\epsilon = \alpha \tilde \epsilon$ - you should be able to show that you can control the result by choosing a fixed $\alpha$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: It seems that the integral can be divergent or not... It seems that I can in fact, by choosing properly the way I take the limit, make it take any value I want...

Comment: Exactly! The "correct" way to solve this way is to split the integral into a sum of improper integrals. Improper her means
$\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm{d}$x
where the function $f$ is bounded on $(a,b]$, and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is undefined. So you always need to split the integral at the singularites, here the singularity is at $x=0$ so you need to study the intgrals
$$
\int_{-c}^c \frac{dx}{x} = \int_{-c}^0 \frac{dx}{x} + \int_0^c \frac{dx}{x}
$$
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce, yes, the integral does not exist either as a Riemann integral or as an improper Riemann integral.  It does, however, exist as a principal value Riemann integral.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, using the adjective "correct" here, even in quotes, is misleading.  The Cauchy principal value is one choice among many for interpreting this integral, none more correct than another.

Comment: Well you simply said it better then me, and I did not try to cause confusion. What I meant by "correct" was as a improper Rieman integral. Seems the poster have some problems realizing there are different interpretations of integrals and convergence, all equally valid.